# How to make an ImageButton disappear when disabled using only xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

This is my first android project,

Matter of fact first programming project ever.

I have an ImageButton that I want to **hide** when it's **disabled**,
The enabled/disabled state is done using xml connection to a viewmodel,
so I can't reference the fragment to do it programmatically.

I tried using a selectorlist to pass in a grayed out version of the image, but I want to hide the button completely not just the src image.

**the button in the fragment layout:**

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/work_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_desktop_windows_black"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="@{timerViewModel.pcButtonState}"
            android:onClick="@{() -> timerViewModel.activityTypeWork()}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gaming_button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.40"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

**The variable controlling the disabled/enabled state:**

```
 val pcButtonState = Transformations.map(lastSession){
        it == null
    }
```

This is done so the button is enabled only when last session is null

So is there anyway to control android:visibility or android:alpha through a selector, or something?

**Thank you...**

---

**Edit**

Problem solved, both my answer and Henry Twist's are correct,

Personally I prefer Henry's approach because it's way easier to implement and maintain.

Comment: Your view has to become part of an Activity somewhere, so you can do it programmatically, just not in the ViewModel.

Comment: Just something to consider, this is a good example of why I don't like binding to ViewModels myself.  Views are now manipulated in more places, which IMO actually complicates things.  Don't bind your view to the ViewModel; manipulate it directly in the fragment or activity.

Comment: @eimmer 
Reason I had to do this in the ViewModel is because the state variable and the onClick are connected to database calls which are maintained in the ViewModel

Comment: @OsamaOmar I understand, but the ViewModel can update a value, expose that value to the activity/fragment and then the view can be updated from there.  IMO, having all dynamic values set in 1 location makes maintenance easier.

Comment: @eimmer yeah I agree, but I'm terribly new to coding. didn't know how exactly to observe the exposed value changes when I made the question.
but as you can see in the answer I posted I figured out how to do that using an observer object.
granted that's not what I settled for, in the end I used Henry's xml approach for now I'm sticking with having all dynamic values in the ViewModel and controlling the UI with the xml lambdas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a need to make the solution this complex, if a button should be hidden when disabled and visible when enabled, you don't need to use the enabled/disabled state at all, you can just set the visibility dependant on `timerViewModel.pcButtonState`.

So for example:

```
android:enabled="true"
android:visibility="@{timerViewModel.pcButtonState ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

---

**Edit**

In order you use external classes in data binding you have to import them in your `data` tag, so:

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />
</data>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the noop question, I'm really very new to all this.
but where should this go?
In the fragment layout file "View" gives an error.
I actually found another solution myself that I'm going to post but I want to understand yours as well...

Comment: Thank you very much, the external classes data import is something completely new to me ^^ 
Can confirm both our solutions works perfectly. 
Gonna accept yours tho, for good sport UwU
(kidding cause it's way more code efficient :D)

Answer (score 0):

Just so, if anyone else came across a similar weird situation

I found a workaround,

By setting up an observer object in the fragment to observe the variable controlling the state

```
val pcButton = binding.pcButton
      
        timerViewModel.pcButtonState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { state ->
            state.let {
                if (it == true) {
                    binding.pcButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        })
```

Now I can programmatically adjust the button properties according to the state of the variable